# Convert monolith application to microservice implementation in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I want to deploy my application in cloud using Kubernetes based deployment. It consits of 3 layers Kafka, Ignite(as DB and processing) and Python(ML engine). 
From Kafka layer we get data stream input which is then passed to Ignite for processing(feature engg). After processing the data is passed to the python
server for further ML predictions. How can I break this monolith application to microservices in Kubernetes? 
Also can using [Istio](https://istio.io/) provide some advantage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible and in fact those tools are easy to deploy in Kubernetes. Firstly, you need to gain some expertise in Kubernetes basics, specially in [statefulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), since Kafka and Ignite are stateful components.

To deploy a Kafka cluster in Kubernetes follow instructions form this repository: https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka

There are other alternatives, but this is the only one I've tested in production environments.

I have not experience with Ignite, this [docs](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-deployment) provides a step-by-step guide. Maybe someone else could share other resources.

About Python, just dockerize your ML model as any other Python app. In the [official docker image for Python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) you'll find a basic Dockerfile to do that. Once you have your docker image pushed to a registry, just create a YAML file describing the [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and apply it to Kubernetes.

As an alternative for the last step, you can use [Draft](https://github.com/Azure/draft/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to dockerize and deploy Python code.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! Did you need any further help to deploy these services?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bitnami/kafka on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/~/dockerfile/)  from bitnami if you want pre-build image.

Export the image to your container registry with the gcloud command.
gcloud docker -- push [your image container registry path]
Deploy the images using [UI](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#step_5_deploy_your_application) or [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#step_5_deploy_your_application)

Expose the port{2181 9092-9099} or which one is exposed in the pulled image after the deployment on kubernetes.

Here is the [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-media/ignite-google-image.tar.gz) of the Ignite image on Google Compute, you have just to deploy it on the kubernetes engine and expose the appropriate ports

For python you have just to Build your python app using dockerfile as ignacio suggested.